# S3 - Spark - Avro read issue

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, avro

Reading Avro files from S3, I have serious performance issues (some executors failing) and I'm seeing these WARN messages in logs:

```
20/03/03 14:41:36 INFO FileScanRDD: Reading File path: s3://path/part-r-00121.avro, range: 939524096-1073741824, partition values: [empty row]
20/03/03 14:41:36 WARN S3AbortableInputStream: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use.
```

I have tried both `spark.read().format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load()` and `context.newAPIHadoopFile` methods to load avro files, both end up exactly with same performance issues. This doesn't happen when I do simple RDD operations like just a count. However when I start doing more complex transformations on RDD with large enough data I start seeing this warning and I have executors failing. Any ideas how I can prevent this? Is there any tuning I can do assuming I have no limits on EMR hardware budget?

Comment: About the data: many small files, a few large files, mix of large and small? About Spark: which version? Note that _"Since Spark 2.4 release, Spark SQL provides built-in support for reading and writing Apache Avro data."_ so you can avoid the awkward `format("blahblah")` syntax -- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/docs/sql-data-sources-avro.md

Comment: Would it make sense to read everything up front and "checkpoint" the raw data on local disks (local to the executors), to make sure the same S3 files are not read again and again later? https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-checkpointing.html